# How does Android keeps track of how much battery each specific apps used?

Tags: battery, battery-life

How does Android keeps track of how much battery each specific apps used?

For example, if you go to battery usage on android phone, it will say something like:

1. Display 70%
2. Whatsapp 25%
3. Browser 3%

etc.

Is this done by battery manager?

And how accurate is this values computed, I am trying to come up with an app that can accurately measure how much battery each apps specifically consume.

Answer (score 0):

There will be low level APIs that Android uses when computing battery stats.

> I am trying to come up with an app that can accurately measure how much battery each apps specifically comsume.

Although this sub isn't for development related questions, check out [Batterystats](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/battery-historian.html) on how to implement battery collection stats.